# Listing files in Google Cloud Storage (nearline) - missing files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm slowly seeding a NAS backup to Google Cloud Storage with rclone. The standard process is to "rclone sync" a big directory, and then run "rclone check" before moving on to the next one.

As of yesterday, rclone started finding missing files in the Google Storage bucket when running "rclone check", and the list of missing files would be different with each invocation.

I was sure it was something with rclone, but then I decided to run gsutil on a VM instance in the cloud, and "gsutil ls" was exhibiting the same problem!

Here's an example (the data in the bucket has not been modified in over 24 hours):

```
vitaly@data-exporter:~$ gsutil ls -lR  gs://bucketname/Photography/2016 |wc
   8817   31667 1034417
vitaly@data-exporter:~$ gsutil ls -lR  gs://bucketname/Photography/2016 |wc
   8810   31643 1033605
vitaly@data-exporter:~$ gsutil ls -lR  gs://bucketname/Photography/2016 |wc
   8813   31656 1033965
vitaly@data-exporter:~$ gsutil ls -lR  gs://bucketname/Photography/2016 |wc
   8818   31671 1034544
vitaly@data-exporter:~$ gsutil ls -lR  gs://bucketname/Photography/2016 |wc
   8816   31664 1034294
```

I am using the Nearline storage class. Regardless of the storage type, shouldn't the listing of bucket contents produce the same number of files?

I would appreciate some ideas. This was working as expected last week.

P.S. I enabled versioning recently, but did not see these issues last week with versioning enabled.

Comment: Google Cloud Storage listings are eventually consistent, so there's no guarantee that they return the same results if the bucket has been recently modified.  That being said, 24 hours is a long time for consistency to catch up.  Could you send mail with the details (include gsutil -D ls logs) to gs-team@google.com?

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency#eventually_consistent_operations. When you say "the data in the bucket has not been modified in over 24 hours", are you essentially saying that the rclone check was still reporting inconsistencies 24 hours after the rclone sync?

Comment: That's correct - 24 hours after the fact I was still getting inconsistencies and files randomly going missing. Of course, 5 hours after posting about the original issue, gsutil now reports the correct files 90% of the time. Still, even if it's an issue of "Google Cloud Storage operations are strongly consistent and which are eventually consistent", 30+ hours to get to that point seems awfully long.