# How do I list all files within a Bucket Subdirectory in PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

After reviewing the PHP Docs for the GCP Storage API and the Bookshelf tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-storage) **I'm lost on how to list the files located in a Bucket subdirectory.**

I've viewed [Listing files in Google Cloud Storage (nearline) - missing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41126478/listing-files-in-google-cloud-storage-nearline-missing-files), however, this code is adapted to Python. **If it really is as simple as using an ls command, how would I run this command from PHP?** I've dug through the repo's on Github from Google and I'm not sure which to use in this case.

I have both of these libraries included via composer. Just to clarify I'm running these remotely from a DigitalOcean Droplet, not from App Engine.

```
"google/appengine-php-sdk": "^1.9",
"google/cloud": "^0.39.2",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an "objects" method that'll do this for you.

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket('my-bucket');
$objects = $bucket->objects([
    'fields' => 'items/name,nextPageToken'
]);

foreach ($objects as $object) {
    echo $object->name() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The documentation for the PHP storage client is over here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.39.2/storage/storageclient

Comment: Brandon: This works for listing all files within a bucket, but not the files within a bucket's "subdirectory" as mentioned in the title.

Is there a way to only fetch those items within a certain subdirectory? Perhaps using a prefix?

Comment: Exactly a prefix. After fields, add this: `'prefix' => 'my/sub/directory/'`

Comment: Using a prefix seems like it will remotely get the whole bucket object, then send it locally to sort the whole object (could be 10,000 files) for a specific subdirectory. How do you get only the subdirectory remotely? I'm going to keep searching the docs and I'll post back here if I find anything.

Comment: The prefix is handled remotely via the API's objects.list `prefix` parameter, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list